Closed form for $\int_0^{\pi/2}\arctan\left(\frac12\sin x\right)\mathrm dx$?

Is there a closed form for $I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\arctan\left(\frac12\sin x\right)\mathrm dx$ ?

Context
Earlier I asked "Find the area of the region enclosed by $\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}=\frac{\sin x+\sin y}{\sin(x+y)}$ and the $x$-axis".

The answer turned out to be $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$, but the proof is non-trivial.
A natural follow-up question is, what happens if we change all the sines to tangents?

So what is the area of the region enclosed by $\frac{\tan x}{\tan y}=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{\tan (x+y)}$ and the $y$-axis, from $y=0$ to $y=\frac{\pi}{2}$ ?
To make the algebra easier, we swap $x$ and $y$, and seek the area enclosed by the new graph and the $x$-axis. Letting $X=\tan x$ and $Y=\tan y$, we have $X\left(\frac{X+Y}{1-XY}\right)=XY+Y^2$. Solving the quadratic in $Y$ gives $y=\arctan\left(\frac12\sin 2x\right)$.
So the area is $\int_0^{\pi/2}\arctan\left(\frac12\sin 2x\right)\mathrm dx$, which equals $\int_0^{\pi/2}\arctan\left(\frac12\sin x\right)\mathrm dx$ due to symmetry.
My attempt
I found that $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arctan(\sin(x))dx=\frac{\pi^2}{8}-\frac{\ln^2(\sqrt{2}-1)}{2}$. I tried to use this method, but it doesn't seem to work, because in my integral there is a $\frac12$, which is not equal to its reciprocal.

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac12\sin x\right)dx\\
= &\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\frac12} \frac {\sin x}{(1+y^2 \sin^2x)}dy \ dx\\=&\int_0^{\frac12} \frac {\sinh^{-1}y}{y \sqrt{1+y^2}}
{dy}\overset{\sinh^{-1}y=\ln\frac{1+t}{1-t}}= \int^{\phi^{-3}}_0\frac{\ln \frac{1+t}{1-t}}{t}dt \\=&\ \text{Li}_2(\phi^{-3}) - \text{Li}_2(-\phi^{-3})
= \frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac32 \ln^2 \phi
\end{align}

+1 Nice! It seems like you can solve challenging integrals on a Post-it.

The antiderivative is very complicated but using the bounds
$$I=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\arctan\left(\frac{\sin (x)}2\right)\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{12} \left(\pi ^2-6 \sinh ^{-1}(2)\,\,
   \text{csch}^{-1}(2)\right)$$
If you use series
$$\arctan\left(\frac{\sin (x)}2\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \,\frac{ \sin ^{2 n+1}(x)}{2^{2 n+1}\,(2 n+1)}$$ you should get the same result simplifying
$$I=\frac{1}{2} \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{4}\right)$$ which is the result of
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \,\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma (n+1)}{2^{2 n+1}\,(2 n+1) \Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$

That is $\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}-\log(2\phi+1)\log\phi\right)$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

@Dan. This is nice !
